# Is documenting assembly-specific information in AssemblyInfo.cs a good practice?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

In most projects I create, I have project or assembly-specific information. The logical place to me seems to be the AssemblyInfo.cs file to place documentation into. I proceeed to transform the AssemblyInfo.cs like this:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Woei")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Woei")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © WoeiWare 2014")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: Guid("44daa4c8-14b5-48ef-b12d-abde36681df8")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]


namespace dStyle.Fields.Properties {
    /// Woei means the wind is blowing hard in The Netherlands
    internal static class Documentation { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say yes, where else would you put it?

One option is to have a master\global assemblyInfo file and keep all common assembly information in this single file which is merged with the project level assemblyinfo.